# "1970-01-01 00:00:00" expires header

Tags: http, firefox, caching, http-headers, browser-cache

I am checking files that are cached in my firefox browser and I note a load of them have an expires (`Expires:`) of:

```
"1970-01-01 00:00:00" expires header
```

This must be a common setting with a common meaning. What exactly?  No expiration set?

Any tips?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means the page expires `1970-01-01 00:00:00`

Which means that they have already expired, this forces the browser to request a fresh version of them every time. Therefore they are not retrieved from the browsers cache.

Here's some more info:

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

Comment: Thanks,  is it an industry convention to use this date?

Comment: Its the Unix start time http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time, Quite a few people use this...

Comment: In our app we use a few HTTP headers to ensure that our dynamic pages are not cached by the browser as we want to "rebuild" a fresh version from the server each time they are request. To do this properly in all browsers you have to set quite a few headers, this explains it well http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Answer (score 1):

The reason "Thursday, 1 January 1970 00:00:00 GMT" is seen so commonly is because it's the official starting point of the Unix Time (aka POSIX time, Unix Epoch Time). So it became a semi-standard way to say "this item has already expired". If it expired at the beginning of time then it will always be expired no matter what the current time is and no matter if the system interpreting it has the correct time set or not. Even if someone changes the system time backward, they cannot go earlier than this, so the item will still be considered expired.